# Resolve these Highly Narcissistic Relations

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

$U$, $V$, $C$ , $D$ , $E$, $F$, $G$, $H$, are distinct digits, varying from 1 to 9.

$UVCD$, $EFGHD$, $EHHEV$ are concatenated numbers.

Please deduce these with concise reasoning from the given relations:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, solve the first equation

> Sqrt(D) is an integer, so must be 1-3. 27^2 is only 3 digits, so Sqrt(D) is 3, and D is 9. X^3 % 10 is 9, so X is 9, so U+V+C % 10 is 9. U+V+C is 19.
>  6859 = (6+8+5)^sqrt(9)

Then, the last equation

> EHHE8 = E^2 * H^H! * 8
>  H<=3, because otherwise H^H! is way too big H>2 because otherwise the total can't reach 5 digits, so H=3, that leaves E=2.
>  23328 = 2 * 3^3! * 2 * 8

And now to attack the middle equation

> 2FG39 = 2^F + G! + 3^9
>  F*1000 + G*100 + 20039 = 2^F + G! + 3^9
>  F*1000 + G*100 + 356 = 2^F + G!
>  G=7, (only 4 digit factorial) so F = 4
>  24739 = 2^4 + 7! + 3^9

Comment: Excellent logic and deduction!!!